# Why magento used deprecatedNode tag in model resource declaration in wishlist

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, resource-model

I have seen an interesting thing in model configuration in config.xml. I was unknown about the tags  `<deprecatedNode>`   in model class declaration and is want to know  about this tags.

In a custom extension we just need this type of model class declaration..

```
 <models>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>[module]_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </[module]>
            <[module]_mysql4>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <[module]>
                        <table>[module]</table>
                    </[module]>
                </entities>
            </[module]_mysql4>
        </models>
```

Reference -http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

`But in magento existing modules` like `Wishlist 's config.xml` define model with deprecatedNode and resourceModel declare with this pattern

```
<wishlist>
                <class>Mage_Wishlist_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>wishlist_resource</resourceModel>
            </wishlist>
<wishlist_resource>

    <class>Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>wishlist_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <wishlist>
                        <table>wishlist</table>
                    </wishlist>
                    <item>
                        <table>wishlist_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <table>wishlist_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <item_option><table>wishlist_item_option</table></item_option>
                </entities>
            </wishlist_resource>
```

WHY THIS TYPE OF CODE USED IN MAGENTO

```
 <resourceModel>wishlist_resource</resourceModel>
                </wishlist>

                <wishlist_resource>

                    <class>Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource</class>
                    <deprecatedNode>wishlist_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions previous to 1.6 the `<resourceModel>` node usually had this name:  `[module]_mysql4`.
Starting with version 1.6 Magento supports (in theory) other types of databases not just mysql. So the resource model name changed to `wishlist_resource`.
but in order to make old extensions that might rewrite the some resource model still work, this `deprecatedNode` was introduced.
If a model or a resource model is not found using the `[module]_resource` tag then Magento looks for it using the `deprecatedNode` value.
Take a look at these methods:
`Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getEntity`

```
public function getEntity($model, $entity)
{
    $modelsNode = Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models;
    $entityConfig = $modelsNode->$model->entities->{$entity};

    /**
     * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
     * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
     * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
     */
    if (isset($modelsNode->$model->deprecatedNode)) {
        $deprecatedNode = $modelsNode->$model->deprecatedNode;
        if (isset($modelsNode->$deprecatedNode->entities->$entity)) {
            $entityConfig = $modelsNode->$deprecatedNode->entities->$entity;
        }
    }

    return $entityConfig;
}
```

and `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName`

```
public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
{
    ....
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    } else {
        /**
         * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
         * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
         * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
         */
        if ($config->deprecatedNode) {
            $deprecatedNode = $config->deprecatedNode;
            $configOld = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->$deprecatedNode;
            if (isset($configOld->rewrite->$class)) {
                $className = (string) $configOld->rewrite->$class;
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Marius ,can you help me in other things...???

Comment: @AmitBera. I hope so. Post your questions and if I can answer them I will.

Comment: Hello Marius ,the link of my question is -http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15084/custom-model-data-checking-issue

Comment: hello marius .please check my link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15084/custom-model-data-checking-issue

Comment: @AmitBera. I saw the question. I just don't have a solution. I see that it already has 2 answers. Maybe one of them works.

Comment: ,Thanks  for your  reply...Let see myself....